# Building Chrome extension using xpath and Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xpath, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently trying to build my first Chrome extension but I'm having a slight issue with my code.

I want to use XMLHTTPRequest and xpath to display a specific number from an external website as a badge on my icon. The code I'm using in my background.js file is as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.com", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // innerText does not let the attacker inject HTML elements.
    document.getElementById("resp").innerText = xhr.responseText;
  }
}


xhr.send();
var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
xmlDoc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

var badgeText = xmldoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//[@id='main']/div/div/section/div[1]/div[2]");

chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: badgeText});
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "#1f729f"});
```

I know this code is probably pretty horrible but this is my first extension and I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting some immediate response after `xhr.send();`

Here the code snipet which is working in one of my extensions (notice **this** in the callback function):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.com", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log("XHR callback readyState = " + this.readyState);
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    // innerText does not let the attacker inject HTML elements.
    document.getElementById("resp").innerText = this.responseText;
    var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
    xmlDoc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

    var badgeText = xmldoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//[@id='main']/div/div/section/div[1]/div[2]");

    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: badgeText});
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "#1f729f"});
  }
}

xhr.send();
```

This way the code would be executed only after the response is available.

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: HI Drasko, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the badgeText still isn't showing my xpath result.

Comment: I have not tried it myself. It was just a pointer how to use an asynchron API. Have you checked if the callback function is being executed? What happened if you set `badgeText` to a constant value?

Comment: I don't think the callback function is being executed. When I set badgeText to a constant value it isn't working either! Think I might need to go back to the drawing board! Any other pointers you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I updated the code in the answer based on the working code from one of my chrome extension.