# Fetch setBadgeText from another URL

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-extension

There is a site, which has metrics (short numbers) to many domains. A special url should be constructed, like `https://metricsite.com?domain=example.com` and this url has then a div with the metric. This is [this site][1].

I want to show this metric as `setBadgeText` on every url. I need something like:

```
$.fetchURL('https://my-metric-site.com/?domain='+window.location.host+'&source=de', XPath(//div[@class='metric']) {
    var metric = data.metric;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:metric});
});
```

What is the way to go to achieve this?

**Update 1**
The desired output in the badge should be:

`//div[@class="data"]/span[@class="value"]/text()`

or

`//div[@class="data-mini"]/span/span[@class="value"]/text()`

The visible results in the `Badge` is a number, like on the screenshot:

[image]

**Update 2**

To get the number directly from the source code one should use [this url][3].

[1]: 
  [3]:

Comment: There's no `div` with `class="metric"` in the link you provided. What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting Sure, it was just an example. I've updated my post with Xpath of desired output.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, that data is loaded dynamically using jscript, so you need a tool like selenium to fetch the data first.

Comment: @JackFleeting Correctly! I found another url to fetch, where these numbers are placed directly in the source code. Xpath expressions are on the new url still the same to address these numbers. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a full answer, but it's too long for a comment and it may get you started:

You can't just use `$.fetchURL` with your url; the site requires certain headers (parameters, cookies, etc.) or else the response is wrong. So first you need to convert those `get` headers to `$.fetchURL`.

Once you do that, this xpath expression

```
//div[@class="data"]/span[@class="value"]/text()
```

should evaluate to

> 401,95

and this one:

```
//div[@class="data-mini"]/span/span/text()
```

should evaluate to

> 436,3

Comment: Could you point me to quick and dirty method of `convert those get headers to $.fetchURL`?

Comment: @Evgeniy - I use the firefox (obviously chrome works as well) Developer tab, Network sub-tab. On the left you'll see the two (in this case) `get` requests. The first one (again, in this case) is the key. Right-click on it, and it you get a "copy" menu item with several options for formats. Copy the one you use and incorporate it in your `fetchUrl'. Sorry it's so complicated, but that's life sometimes...

Comment: You've helped me to find the seemingly correct solution!!!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22267609/1992004 - Should this code work outta `background.js`? Or are there any other rules for `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @Evgeniy - I'm afraid that's above my pay grade :D. You may want to post it as a separate question; there are many smart people who know this stuff...